# Getting siblings records in a has_many, :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

Given this `has_many, :through` scenario:

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :issue, :name, :id, :brand_ids

  has_many :publications
  has_many :docs, :through => :publications
  has_many :silos
  has_many :brands, :through => :silos
end
```

**brand.rb**

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :logo1, :logo2, :colour1, :colour2

  has_many :users
  has_many :prices, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :silos
  has_many :articles, :through => :silos
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessor :current_password
  attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :email, :remember_me, :brand_id
  belongs_to :brand
end
```

How would I write a scope or a method or a helper to get `Article` records that share a `Brand` with the current user? Something along these lines:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :branded_articles, lambda { |user| where('brand_ids = ?', user.brand) }
end
```

**EDIT**

Something like this should work, right? I just can't figure out the syntax.

```
Article.all.brands.find(1) #should find all articles available to a brand with an ID of 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was irritatingly simple:

```
@articles = current_user.brand.articles
```

With any luck that helps someone else.